# Sorting by column in an XPages view data source

Tags: view, xpages

I have a dynamic view control (my own) which is fed by a configurable view data source. I need to be able to sort the view by various columns. Is there a way to do it with the view data source or do I need to roll my own? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I guess that you need to build up the entries. Nothing with data source.

Answer (score 3):

For efficiency reasons, sorting should be handled by the domino runtime. The view must have the right columns either tagged as sorted or sortable by user. This creates the indexes within the NSF.
Then, the data source has some properties to control with sort index in being used, based on the name of the column you want to sort. The extlib DataView controls shows how this can be done in Java, through a JSF DataModel.
Also, you might consider using the DynamicViewpanel from the extlib/up1, as it does all of this for you.